# I built a library from source and the libs are in ~/Desktop/xerces -- how do I install these libs so the linker can find them?

Tags: 12.04

I have a bunch of .so libs in ~/Desktop/xerces after building the library from source. I would now like to install these libraries (say in /usr/lib) and have them picked up by ld. I manually copied the libs into /usr/lib with sudo mv but it did not work (and I think that's the bad-style way to do it anyway).

Comment: See here: [Installation:Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/install-3.html#Unix) under Binary Distribution

Answer (score 0):

I Will Bold the part relative to my comment.

Taken From: [Xerces, Unix Installation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/install-3.html#Unix)

---

### Binary distribution

Install the binary distribution xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler}.tar.gz by extracting the files from the compressed archive. Here {arch} denotes the CPU architecture, {os} denotes the operating system, and {compiler} denotes the C++ compiler of your choice. For example:

```
gzip -d xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4.tar.gz
tar -xf xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4.tar
```

This will create an 'xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4' sub-directory containing the Xerces-C++ binary distribution.

You will need to add the xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler}/bin directory to your PATH environment variable:

For Bourne Shell, K Shell or Bash, type:

```
export PATH="$PATH:<full-path-to-xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler}>/bin"
```

For C Shell, type:

```
setenv PATH "$PATH:<full-path-to-xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler}>/bin"
```

**If you wish to make this setting permanent, you need to change your profile by changing your setup files which can be either .profile or .kshrc.**

In addition, you will also need to set the library search path. (LIBPATH on AIX, LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Solaris and Linux, SHLIB_PATH on HP-UX, and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X).

In the following shell commands, the  denotes the full path to the xerces-c-3.1.1-{arch}-{os}-{compiler} directory. For Bourne Shell, K Shell or Bash, type:

```
export LIBPATH=<xerces-path>/lib:$LIBPATH (AIX)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<xerces-path>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Solaris, Linux)
export SHLIB_PATH=<xerces-path>/lib:$SHLIB_PATH (HP-UX)
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<xerces-path>/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (Mac OS X)
```

For C Shell, type:

```
setenv LIBPATH "<xerces-path>/lib:$LIBPATH" (AIX)
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "<xerces-path>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" (Solaris, Linux)
setenv SHLIB_PATH "<xerces-path>/lib:$SHLIB_PATH" (HP-UX)
setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "<xerces-path>/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" (Mac OS X)
```

The binary distribution contains the pre-built parser libraries and sample executables. Please refer to the [Samples](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/samples-3.html) for how to run the samples.

---

**Update**

Whether Source Or Binary, the library paths must be exported using one of the snippets above as the export statement tells the compiler and linker where to look for your libraries.

**Update 2**

In case this fails, you can install [xerces-c from the repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xerces-c) using `sudo apt-get install xerces-c`

Comment: Thank you for the time to post your answer, however, I would like to practice building from source. I want to finish up my build process and figure out the step to get the libs I compiled into the right place.

Comment: That is the Step in bold plus the Code, whether source or binary.  See update

Comment: I would like a system wide installation so I think they would belong in /usr/local/lib (or /usr/local/lib64?)

Comment: a system-wide installation is usually /usr/lib.  The bitness doesn't matter, as /usr/lib64 and /usr/lib are normally symlinked in a multilib system.  Just add the appropriate PATH in the correct `export` command from above.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu `ld.so` find and load the shared libraries needed by a program using the cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache` and the default path `/lib`, and then `/usr/lib`.

According to ldconfig manual:

> ldconfig  creates,  updates,  and removes the necessary links and
>   cache (for use by the run-time linker,  ld.so)  to  the  most  recent 
>   shared libraries  found  in  the directories specified on the command
>   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
>   (/usr/lib  and /lib).   ldconfig  checks the header and file names of
>   the libraries it encounters when determining which  versions  should 
>   have  their  links updated.   ldconfig ignores symbolic links when
>   scanning for libraries.

You should copy your library in `/path/as/you/like/lib` directory and create your ld configuration file:

```
   sudo echo "/path/as/you/like/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myLibrary.conf
```

After that, run:

```
   sudo ldconfig -v
```

If `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` doesn't exists, you should add your line ad the end of `/etc/ld.so.conf` file.

Here is the link to [ldconfig manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/ldconfig.8.html) for more details